# conditions for the given quadratic forms to be equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, equivalence-relations, quadratic-forms

consider the two quadratic forms Q and P given by

1 Q(x,y,z,w) = $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + bw^2$

2 P(x,y,z,w) = $x^2 + y^2 +  czw$

the source of the question says that P and Q are equivalent over R  if b and c are non zero real numbers with b negative *( i would further like to state that quality of source is not reliable ,.,,answers had been wrong in past too . )*

i am not able to figure out why do we need that b to be negative ?

consider the matrix from the first quadratic form

\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&b\end{bmatrix}

and the matrix from second  quadratic form

\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&\frac{c}{2}\\0&0&\frac{c}{2}&0\end{bmatrix}

i think P and Q must be equivalent over R  if b and c are non zero real numbers ?? please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: yes its $w^2$ thanks

Comment: The matrix of the second quadratic form should be $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac c 2 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac c 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$ Isn't it so @ANUJ NAIN?

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues of the second matrix are $$\{1, \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{c^2 + 1}}{2}\},$$

with $1$ appearing with multiplicity $2$. Therefore, when $c \neq 0$, $P$ has maximal rank and its signature is $(3,1)$. In general $Q$ will be equivalent to $P$ iff both their ranks and signature coincide, so, in this case, iff $b < 0$.

Comment: thankyou that helped , the general condition that you mentioned ( In general $Q$ will be equivalent to $P$ iff both their ranks and signature coincide, ) will that hold over complex feild $C$  also

Comment: @ANUJNAIN It's simpler over the complex numbers, essentially because there every number has a square root. The result, then, is that two complex quadratic forms are equivalent iff they have the same rank. (Any symmetric complex matrix is congruent to one of the form $\operatorname{diag}(1,\ldots,1,0,\ldots,0)$.)